# What's the fastest way to connect vertices in corners (a very common situation when modeling)?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Sure I could select vertices 2 by 2 and hit the J key but no one want to do this repetitive work, so what's the best way to deal with those?

Comment: because you are connecting 3 vertices on one side to a different number (5) on the other, the fastest way is to use the knife tool.  Remember to end each cut with E so that you can continue to make cuts.  If the number of vertices were the same there are other tricks.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any other way than using J or using the knife (K). If there was no face (so you could delete your face) you could easily fill with Ctrl F > Grid Fill